# How to hide IOS safari (13.0) toolbar using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

According to MacRumours, "In iOS 13 though, you can get Safari to hide the toolbar completely when navigating a website, which makes for a less disruptive experience." and it works as stated. Now, I would like to do the same thing using code (JavaScript) without having the user to manually click "Hide Toolbar" to hide it. Is it possible to access "Smart Search (AA icon)" through JavaScript?

[image: Current behaviour]

**Thanks In Advance**